removing dead citrix apps from applications menu?
Once upon a time I visited my employer's citrix portal to connect to a work computer from home using a citrix-ified version of windows remote desktop. It worked pretty well, but unfortunately, whatever it had me install created faux application icons for every dang app my very large employer packed up as a citrix app. That was bad enough, but since upgrading to 24.04 these apps are now nonfunctional, and I would like to remove them.
I have tried to even find these "apps" in

software updater
synaptic
apt
apt-get
dpkg
snap

And can't seem to find them registered w/any of those facilities.
I would like to remove these entries & clean up my application menu. Is there a way to do it (without e.g., reinstalling the os or anything else drastic)?
A portion of my application menu, with garbage apps moved into 'unnamed folders'

Check for desktop entries in /home/(your-user-name)/.local/share/applications

ah--yes! There they are--and they are removable. Thank you!

I'll write it as an answer and you can accept it if you like.

You may find these as desktop entries in /home/(your-user-name)/.local/share/applications
If that is where they are, you should be able to delete them from there.
